# What is the best practice to add "required" class in MVC razor view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, data-annotations

I am trying to add `required` class in HTML text box by using data annotation but I can't. My understanding is, MVC should handle this if data annotation is used. I should not need to add `required` on top of annotation. If I am wrong then, is this good practice?

**View:**

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new { @class = "first-name",  placeholder = "Required" })
```

**Model:**

```
[Display(Name = "First Name")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide a First Name")]
[MaxLength(40)]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

**HTML in Chrome DevTools:**

[image]

**If I add `required = "required"` in view then I see expected result, like this:**

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new { @class = "first-name", placeholder = "Required", required = "required" })
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: `required="required"` is a HTML-5 validation attribute (client side only) and has nothing to do with MVC's validation.

Comment: Adding a `[Required]` attribute will add associated `data-val-*` attributes (and if they are not being added as per your first html snippet, it means the input is not inside a form, or you have disabled client side validation.